# Why are there slight different behaviors with array accesses?

Tags: ruby

My array is:

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

array[4,0] gives []
```

But:

```
array[5,0] gives nil
```

I was suspecting `array[4,0]` should also give nil as the array has only a third index which is `:jelly`.

Can any Ruby punters out there clarify this behaviour?

Comment: @falsetru Almost _exact_ duplicate, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> Additionally, an empty array is returned when the starting index for an element range is at the end of the array.
>
> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.